# webpack with angular 1 and bower

Tags: angularjs, webpack, bower

I'm building an app that uses webpack to bundle all of my javascript, node modules, and bower components. I was able to get angular and node modules working on their own, but when I tried to include my bower components I get the following error

```
app.bundle.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: angular.module is not a function
```

what my webpack build looks like

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BowerWebpackPlugin = require("bower-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
  loaders: [
    {test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css"},
    {test: /\.(woff|svg|ttf|eot)([\?]?.*)$/, loader: "file-loader?name=[name].[ext]"}
  ],
  context: __dirname + '/web',
  entry: {
    app: './app.js',
    vendor: ['angular']
  },
  resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ["web_modules", "node_modules", "bower_components"]
    },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist/js',
    filename: 'app.bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin( /* chunkName= */ "vendor", /* filename= */ "vendor.bundle.js"),
    new BowerWebpackPlugin({
      excludes: /.*\.less/
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $:      "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
    })
  ],
  extensions: ['', '.json', '.js']
};
```

inside of my app.js (angular app declaration file) I have this

```
var angular = require('angular');
require("jquery");
require("bootstrap");

angular.module('App', []);

require('./services');
require('./controllers');
require('./directives');
```

How can I resolve this issue?

EDIT** I'm starting to think it has something to do with using the same entry point for the commonschunkplugin and the bowerwebpackplugin

Answer (score 3):

In my npm-based project that uses Browserify, I had a similar issue.  Then I noticed either on another discussion or in the docs it was said (paraphrasing):

> do not store angular in a var as it creates issues with the global reference to angular

So instead of

```
var angular = require('angular');
```

try

```
require('angular');
```

and still call `angular.module( name, [])` as you normally would.  My guess is that whatever returns from `require('angular')` is `undefined` or doesn't provide the angular APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll avoid making angular global. It didn't resolve my issue but I'll keep it in mind. Looks like it works (without bower components) when i remove the bower webpack and resolve plugins at the bottom. And it works (without angular) when I add these.

Comment: I haven't specifically used webpack so it was just a guess.  Sorry it didn't help fix the issue.  I do plan to move away from Browserify to webpack because I want to use a lazy loading library to build out separate sub-apps.